# Ansible Windows - Module "community.general.ini_file" - Not working

Tags: windows, ansible, ansible-pull

I have installed ansible using Cygwin and need to make some changes in ini and config files. However, some of the modules are not working.. Pasting Error below:

---

## *community.general.ini_file:*

[WARNING]: No pythonfatal: [EC interpret2AMAZ-JOJ7ers found EVD]: FAILfor host EED! => {"aC2AMAZ-JOJnsible_fac7EVD (triets": {"disd ['/usr/bcovered_inin/python'terpreter_, 'python3python": ".7', 'pyth/usr/binon3.6', 'python"}, "ython3.5',changed":  'python2.false, "mo7', 'pythodule_stdern2.6', '/ur": "Excepsr/libexection calli/platform-ng "Creatpython', 'e" with /usr/bin/p"1" argumython3',
'ent(s): "python'])
At line:4 char:21\r\n+ def _ansiballz_main():\r\n+                     ~\r\nAn expression was expected after '('.\r\nAt line:13 char:27\r\n+     except (AttributeError, OSError):\r\n+                         ~\r\nMissing argument in parameter list.\r\nAt line:15 char:7\r\n+     if scriptdir is not None:\r\n+       ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:7\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,\r\n+       ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r\nAt line:22 char:30\r\n+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                              ~\r\nMissing expression after ','.\r\nAt line:22 char:25\r+     if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                         ~\r\nThe '<' operator is reserved for future use.\r\nAt line:27 char:34\r\n+     def invoke_module(modlib_path, temp_path, json_params):\r\n+                                ~\r\nMissing argument in parameter list.\r\nAt line:28 char:40\r\n+         z = zipfile.ZipFile(modlib_path, mode='a')\r\n+                                        ~\r\nMissing argunt in parameter list.\r\nAt line:31 char:33\r\n+         zinfo = zipfile.ZipInfo()\r\n+                                 ~\r\nAn expression was expected after '('.\r\nAt line:34 char:25\r\n+         z.writestrinfo, sitecustomize)\r\n+                         ~\r\nMissing argument in parameter list.\r\nNot all parse errors were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again."\r\nAt line:6 char:1\r\n+ $exec_wpper = [ScriptBlock]::Create($split_parts[0])\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException\r\n    + FullyQualifiErrorId : ParseException\r\n \r\nThe expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an object that was not valid. It must result in a command \r\nname, a script block, or a CommandInfo object.\r\nAt line char:2\r\n+ &$exec_wrapper\r\n+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadExpression\r\n ", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
[image]

My end goal is to make changes in the .ini or Config files of windows.

Answer (score 1):

Most Ansible modules were created for Linux. For administering Windows, there's a collection dedicated for that OS:

https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/windows

Of note for your use case is the following module:

[community.windows.win_lininfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_lineinfile_module.html#ansible-collections-community-windows-win-lineinfile-module)

- This module will search a file for a line, and ensure that it is present or absent.
- This is primarily useful when you want to change a single line in a file only.

If you wanted to add/replace/delete multiple lines, you could call this module multiple times.

Comment: lineinfile is not working properly for INI files.. Actually INI files contains Sections such as [SECTION1] [SECTION2].. it doesn't work on the section based.. for example if I want to add a line in particular section, lineinfile adds it as a last line. 

Can we tweak with Lineinfile for this particular challenge. ???

Comment: Negative. The win_lininfile module is limited as you've seen. You might be able to do what you want using the [insertafter parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/windows/win_lineinfile_module.html#parameter-insertafter).From what you've mentioned, you're probably looking more for the ansible.builtin.blockinfile module. That said, that module currently doesn't exist for Windows. You'll have to think outside the box on this one which, using Ansible, would most likely mean creating your own module.